# "buying cookies will deliver on our promise" - can I use subject and verb like this?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, subjects, verbing

A bit of context: a couple decided not to spend money on unecessary stuff and they promised that to each other.
Later, one of them says:

> I dont believe that buying cookies will deliver on our promise.

Also that would mean - subject and a verb - "buying cookies will deliver" which I have a problem with as the "**buying itself cannot deliver on a promise**".

I would write it like this:

> I dont believe that by/with buying cookies we will deliver on our
>   promise.

Would that be the same?

Comment: "buying cookies" as a concept

Comment: *Buying* is a noun (gerund) which can be a subject.

Comment: Does he means to say "If we buy some cookies, we will have broken our promise"? If so, I guess your phrase should be re-built with "deliver" cut out. "Deliver" has the sense of "accomplished", like "accomplished a task", IMHO. A promise to abstain from something is a different one, it may not be announced accomplished, unless the person who had given the promise has died or unless he established some time limit for himself.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Sure, I know it is a subject but does it make a sense? Because "buying" cannot (itself) deliver on a promise.

Comment: Yes, it's fine. It means "the act of buying cookies".

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to say "I don't believe (that) buying cookies would help us keep/uphold our promise"?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is both grammatical and logical.

The speaker is evaluating something, *buying cookies* (which is a gerund phrase used as a noun). She is determining that the act of *buying cookies* will not accomplish something. It has the same logic as

> He is hungry.  Eating will solve that.

This means

> His eating will solve that.

This is functionally the same as

> He will solve that by eating.

Obviously there is *someone* (or something) doing the *paying*. But that is always the case with gerunds. The person or thing doing or experiencing the gerund is often left unstated, and perhaps even unknown.

The original sentence could be expanded to

> I don't believe that [our] buying cookies will deliver on our promise.

The gerund is the subject of the clause *that X will deliver on our promise*.

Yes, the first sentence is equivalent to

> I don't believe that by/with buying cookies we will deliver on our promise.

The difference is structural, not logical. The gerund phrase, *buying cookies* is now part of an adverbial phrase *by buying cookies* that modifies *will deliver* rather than being the subject of *will deliver* in the first sentence.